# SQLAlchemy: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an instance of a table with the following code:

```
c = 'dcoh92j'
new_comment = Comment(rcomment = c, rtime = datetime.datetime.now())
```

But I receive this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO comments (rcomment, rtime) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (Comment(id='dcoh92j'), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 20, 12, 38, 38, 836433))
```

Here is my table schema:

```
class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('comment_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    rcomment = Column(String)
    rtime = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Comment(rcomment='{0}', rtime='(1)')>".format(self.rcomment, self.rtime)
```

1. Why does SQLAlchemy think the parameters I'm trying to insert into the database are `(Comment(id='dcoh92j'), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 20, 12, 38, 38, 836433)`? Instead of just `'dcoh92j'` and `2017, 1, 20, 12, 38, 38, 836433`
2. Where is this `Comment(id='dcoh92j')` coming from?

Full code [here](https://github.com/Logicmn/Reddit-Stock-Bot/blob/master/src/stock_bot.py).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I ended up figuring it out. Of course after 3 hours of bug testing and ripping out my hair, it was a simple matter of wrapping `c` and `datetime.datetime.now()` in str() tags.

Fix:

`new_comment = Comment(rcomment = str(c), rtime = str(datetime.datetime.now()))`

Answer (score 1):

You define `rtime = Column(String)` as a string field but `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` is a datetime object. So instead of String field use `DateTime`:

```
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
rtime = Column(DateTime)
```

or convert datetime object to a string:

```
str_rtime = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
new_comment = Comment(rcomment=c, rtime=str_rtime)
```

Comment: Didn't work, are you sure DateTime is an object? It throws the error `NameError: name 'DateTime' is not defined` in reference to `rtime = Column(DateTime)`

Comment: Yes it is. Did you import it `from sqlalchemy import DateTime`

Comment: Or use second method dont change your field type just cast your datetime value to a string

Comment: Thank you, that was half of it. The other half was wrapping `c` in a `str()` tag.